# Call By Reference error in javascript(edited)

Tags: javascript

just try to run this code in two ways:

1) run this code below;
2) enable `for` loop then run it

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function toggle(){
        //console.log('hi');

        var samplediv = document.getElementById('samplediv');
        samplediv.innerHTML = '';

        var i = 1;
        //for(var i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
            samplediv.innerHTML +=
                "<div id=\'jh"+ i + "\'>Hi This is "+i+"</div>" +
                "<div id=\'edit"  + i +  "\' style=\'display:none\'>Edit "+i+"</div>" ;
                document.getElementById('jh'+i).addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById('edit'+i).style.display="block";});
            /*
            (function(i){
                //console.clear();
                var key = i;
                i += "";
                document.getElementById('jh0').addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById('edit0').style.display="block";});
                //document.getElementById('jh'+key).addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById('edit'+key).style.display="none";}, true);
                //console.log(i, key);
            }(i));
            */
        //}
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="samplediv" >over here</div>

<script>toggle();</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to add addEventLister on every divs using `for`. I'm sure this is kind of call by reference error. I know there are ways to add events such as `on` attribute method. Also adding a number of similar listeners is inefficient but I have to make them as you can see.

I've made a IIFE to make key be a value but failed. Do you have any idea to solve this problem?(No jQuery please)

Comment: You don't clearly explain how your code is failing, but this is possibly a duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Thanks for a help but that is not the answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/977yckqh/)

1. You will change method which You use to adding new elements.
   I replaced `innerHTML +=` to `document.createElement` for each new item.

   ```
   var jh = document.createElement('div');
   jh.id = 'jh'+i;
   jh.innerText = 'Hi This is '+i;

   var edit = document.createElement('div');
   edit.id = 'edit'+i;
   edit.style.display = 'none';
   edit.innerText = 'Edit '+i;

   samplediv.appendChild(jh).appendChild(edit);
   ```
2. Variable `i` on `click` event is visible with last value, so You must get index from other source (from `id` for example).

   ```
   document.getElementById('jh'+i).addEventListener("click", function(){

       var jhIndex = this.id.split('jh')[1];
       document.getElementById('edit'+jhIndex).style.display= 'block';
   });
   ```

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!! That's what I searched for over a day!
p.s) why can't I say 'thanks' in this comment form? is this comment ok?

Comment: No problem. Comment must be minimum 15 letters.

Comment: One question again, What made a variable visible with last value? I think it has its purpose.

Comment: Variable is visible with last value, because Your clicking on div, when loop was done. You dont send variable with current value to `addEventListener` callback function.